# Anonymous website

Tags: security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How hard is to be the anonymous owner of a website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-hard-is-to-be-the-anonymous-owner-of-a-website)

Is it possible to setup a website anonymously?

I want to setup a domain and hosting but I don't want people to be able to track it back to me.

Is this possible? / What are my options?

EDIT

I want to be able to use PHP and some SQL db. So it cannot be static

Comment: Do you want to be anonymous because you don't want to ever be associated to it? e.g. its a porn site... you like the profit but it would not look good to your wife/family/neighbors. Or are you hoping to create a startup site that you want on the hush hush or don't want your current boss to know about? Or are you simply trying to avoid the spam and domain renewal scams etc.?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to be 100% anonymous. Even if your personal information is hidden through private registration it is still captured by the registrar and your web host. You can make it slightly more difficult by using private registration and using companies outside of the US but you information is always available if someone wants it bad enough.